# Bug in python tokenize?

Tags: python, tokenize

Why would this

```
if 1 \
and 0:
    pass
```

simplest of code choke on tokenize/untokenize cycle

```
import tokenize
import cStringIO

def tok_untok(src):
    f = cStringIO.StringIO(src)
    return tokenize.untokenize(tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline))

src='''if 1 \\
and 0:
    pass
'''
print tok_untok(src)
```

It throws:

```
AssertionError:
File "/mnt/home/anushri/untitled-1.py", line 13, in <module>
  print tok_untok(src)
File "/mnt/home/anushri/untitled-1.py", line 6, in tok_untok
  tokenize.untokenize(tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tokenize.py", line 262, in untokenize
  return ut.untokenize(iterable)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tokenize.py", line 198, in untokenize
  self.add_whitespace(start)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tokenize.py", line 187, in add_whitespace
  assert row <= self.prev_row
```

Is there a workaround without modifying the src to be tokenized (it seems `\` is the culprit)

Another example where it fails is if no newline at end e.g. `src='if 1:pass'` fails with same error

Workaround:
But it seems  using untokenize different way works

```
def tok_untok(src):
    f = cStringIO.StringIO(src)
    tokens = [ t[:2] for t in tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline)]
    return tokenize.untokenize(tokens)
```

i.e. do not pass back whole token tuple but only  t[:2]

though [python doc](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.untokenize) says extra args are skipped

> Converts tokens back into Python source code. The iterable must return
>   sequences with at least two elements,
>   the token type and the token string.
>   Any additional sequence elements are
>   ignored.

Comment: It works OK in Python 2.5, throws the AssertionError on 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a [known bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue9974) and there is interest in a cleaner patch than the one attached to that issue. Perfect time to contribute to a better Python ;)